# How to pass a variable to other screen without Navigation with Bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

in my `HomeView` I have a variable `List<String>` and I want to pass it to `SecondView` without navigating to the SecondView. I'm using Bloc for Authentication, could I use Bloc also to pass variable between screens without navigating?
Which is the best way? Are there any example or references?

Comment: What do you mean without navigating? What do you expect your second screen to do, if not navigated to?

Comment: I want to send multiple `List` to `SecondView` and then access and display them only when the user will navigate effectively there

Comment: Well, you can use BloC to keep those lists as a state of your application, that is what BLoC does: state management. Your second screen will only get the data once it's navigated to though. Regardless of wether you navigate via Router or BLoC or other means.

Comment: If the `SecondView` widget isn't displayed, that means that it's not in the widget tree. This also mean that the `SecondView` widget isn't currently created. There is no way to pass data to an non existing object